# Loopless program to remove duplicate elements in a sorted array

Tags: python

I want to write a loopless program (probably using comprehension) to remove duplicate elements in a sorted array in Python (and most efficiently too).

Comment: You can just use `sorted(set(a))` -- and your array doesn't even have to be sorted to start with!

Comment: Why loopless? Is this homework?

Comment: @Gabe, That works fine _if_ all the objects are hashable (usually they are, but noone ever seems to mention it in their questions)

Comment: A comprehension _is_ a loop

Comment: @gnibbler: No, a comprehension *uses* a loop. It's not a loop any more than `list(thing)` or `all(thing)` is a loop.

Comment: @user2357112, those are loops too. Look at the implementation

Comment: @gnibbler: You're conflating things with parts of their implementation. It's analogous to saying that a car is an engine. Let me put it this way. A comprehension is an expression. A loop is not an expression. Therefore, a comprehension is not a loop, whether or not it uses one.

Comment: You can't not use a loop, unless you meant that the code itself should be devoid of the typical looping constructs of `while`, `for`, etc.

Comment: @user2357112, it's important to remember that list comprehensions are loops when calculating the time complexity of an algorithm. I don't think there's any useful reason for defining them to not be loops. You are saying you can get from A to B without an engine because you're using a car

Comment: @gnibbler: Practical reason? It helps direct people away from constructions like `[print(x) for x in thing]`. Loops are control flow tools. List comprehensions are a way of building lists. It's good to keep them separate, even if the list comprehension is a thin wrapper around a loop.

Comment: @gnibbler: That's why I posted as a comment rather than an answer!

Comment: I'm not saying you can get from A to B without an engine because you're using a car. I'm just saying the thing you're driving isn't an engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the list is sorted - meaning all the duplicates are already grouped, you can use `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> testList = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [k for k, g in groupby(testList)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This is more efficient (in memory and time) that converting to a set and sorting. It also has the advantage of only needing to compare for equality, so works ok for unhashable items too.

Answer (score 5):

I would personally just use this.

```
>>> testList = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9]
>>> sorted(set(testList))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You can even sort a list from the beginning.

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> shuffle(testList)
>>> testList
[1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 9, 8, 1, 7, 8]
>>> sorted(set(testList))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: This solution not most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

To take advantage of the existing order, you'd want to use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). With no `key` argument, `itertools.groupby` groups runs of equal elements in the argument iterable:

```
import itertools

newlist = [key for key, group in itertools.groupby(oldlist)]
```

This runs in O(n), whereas `sorted(set(oldlist))` runs in O(nlog(n)).

Answer (score 1):

According this [article](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark), the fastest way to uniqify a list without preserving the order is:

```
def f9(seq):
    # Not order preserving
    return {}.fromkeys(seq).keys()
```

You can view the benchmark script here: http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark/uniqifiers_benchmark.py

Comment: That article is from before Python had built-in sets, though. Back then, `Set` and `ImmutableSet` were wrappers around `dict`, implemented in Python. These days, `set` beats `dict` for set operations.

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`

```
testList = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9]

import numpy
print numpy.unique(testList)
```